# Latest build in crashlytics is showing message that "investigation recommended"

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

Our crashes are not reporting in Crashlytics, we are getting  message "investigation recommended"

Please find the [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI0fg.png).

Comment: could you find solution , How to see crashes report, we also facing same issue .

Answer (score 2):

Please Make sure the following things.

1) your debug information formate set to **DWARF with dlsym File**
  GoTo File Navigation -> select xcodeFile -> Build Settings -> Debug Information Format

2) [image: Make sure no any missing dsym at Fabric server.]

if any missing dsym warning appeared at server.
Please select respected version from same screen as shown in screenshot,
and disable that version

[image: and now select highlighted link in screenshot]